# C++ edit box justification in Windows CE

Tags: c++, mfc, windows-ce

I'm using C++ (MFC) to develop a Windows CE 6 application.

If I put an edit box on a dialogue I can justify the text at design time in the Dialogue editor without problem.

However, when I deploy the application to the target device the text is always left-justified. If I use m_EditVariable.ModifyStyle(ES_RIGHT | ES_LEFT, ES_CENTER) the text is still always left justified.

Am I doing something silly or does WinCE not allow justification?

Thanks for looking
DerekJ

Comment: Your code is correct, In windows 8 its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desktop OS supports justification, therefore the designer running on the desktop lays it out properly.  Windows CE doesn't support justification, however, so that's why it fails to justify on the device at runtime.